# MySQL group by hour epoch time

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, back, epoch

So this is to show how many connection my platform had in a period in range of hour.

Where I comment "variable" it's what will be received from the front end, this query will run in the backend to populate a chart.

```
SELECT
    count(server_events.event_type),
    server_events.time_stamp,
    hotspots.partner_id,
    hotspots.partner,
    hotspots.operator_id
FROM
    `msp-data`.server_events
INNER JOIN 
    `adserver`.hotspots, `adserver`.operator
WHERE 
    server_events.time_stamp between "1591930800" and "1592017199" -- variable
    and server_events.event_type = "auth_final"
    and server_events.nas_id = adserver.hotspots.code
    and hotspots.partner_id = "1" -- variable
    and hotspots.operator_id = "2" -- variable
GROUP BY
    server_events.time_stamp div 3600
ORDER BY
    server_events.time_stamp
```

This is my current output
I posted the full query, but in this output I didn't get partner and filters of partner_id or operator_id

```
count time_stamp partner_id operator_id
6   1591944931  1   1
12  1591945711  1   5
6   1591952103  1   1
36  1591952621  1   1
18  1591956063  1   1
12  1591962118  1   4
6   1591966538  1   1
6   1591968554  1   1
12  1591973267  1   5
18  1591976918  1   1
18  1591978620  1   5
12  1591983139  1   5
12  1591984830  1   1
24  1591989873  1   1
12  1591993080  1   1
30  1591995612  1   1
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmMlq.png)

Expected output would be

```
10 1591930800-1591934399 
15 1591934400-1591937999
```

Comment: Your query should fail.  The `SELECT` columns are incompatible with the `GROUP BY`.  You need to better explain what you want to do.

Comment: Incidentally, including mathematical operators within table/column identifiers is a cataclysmically poor idea.

Comment: Edit question to show sample data and desired output as text tables.

Comment: What I expect is to know how many "auth_final" event_type per hour so something like.

10 1591930800 - 1591934399
15 1591934400 - 1591937999

Comment: @FábioMagnoni if you put something together on http://sqlfiddle.com/ with your table schema and this test data it will be a lot easier for others to help you figure out the query itself because we'll have a working example to build from. Please read over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information. Making it easy for others to test and explore your data will make it a lot easier for you to get a working solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try executing below. And try considering Strawberry's advice.

```
SELECT SUM(CNT), TM FROM(SELECT DISTINCT
    count(server_events.event_type) OVER(PARTITION BY hotspots.partner_id,hotspots.partner,hotspots.operator_id,server_events.time_stamp/3600) CNT
    server_events.time_stamp/3600 TM
FROM
    `msp-data`.server_events
INNER JOIN 
    `adserver`.hotspots, `adserver`.operator
WHERE 
    server_events.time_stamp between "1591930800" and "1592017199" -- variable
    and server_events.event_type = "auth_final"
    and server_events.nas_id = adserver.hotspots.code
    and hotspots.partner_id = "1" -- variable
    and hotspots.operator_id = "2" -- variable
)    
GROUP BY TM
ORDER BY
    2
```

Under Mysql Version 12

```
SELECT SUM(CNT), TM FROM(SELECT 
    count(A.event_type) cnt,
hotspots.partner_id,hotspots.partner,hotspots.operator_id,tm
FROM
    (SELECT A.time_stamp/3600 AS TM,A.* FROM `msp-data`.server_events A ) A
INNER JOIN 
    `adserver`.hotspots, `adserver`.operator
WHERE 
    A.time_stamp between "1591930800" and "1592017199" -- variable
    and A.event_type = "auth_final"
    and A.nas_id = adserver.hotspots.code
    and hotspots.partner_id = "1" -- variable
    and hotspots.operator_id = "2" -- variable
    group by hotspots.partner_id,hotspots.partner,hotspots.operator_id,TM
)     aliaz
GROUP BY TM
ORDER BY
    2
```

Comment: The output is from your query is

`6 442206.9253 1 1
6 442207.1419 1 5
6 442207.9306 1 5
6 442208.9175 1 1
6 442209.0614 1 1
6 442209.2531 1 1
6 442209.3533 1 4
6 442209.4050 1 4
6 442209.4150 1 2
6 442209.4969 1 4
6 442210.0175 1 1
6 442210.1089 1 1
6 442210.4747 1 1
6 442211.6994 1 4
6 442211.7619 1 5
6 442212.9272 1 1
6 442213.4872 1 1
6 442214.0711 1 4
6 442214.7964 1 5
6 442215.4461 1 1
6 442215.5736 1 1
6 442215.8106 1 1
6 442216.2833 1 5
6 442216.2908 1 2
6 442216.7419 1 1
6 442217.5386 1 5
6 442217.6267 1 5
6 442218.0083 1 1
6 442218.3764 1 1`

Comment: Edited my answer. Check it @FábioMagnoni

Comment: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY hotspots.partner_id,hotspots.partner,hotspots.operator_id,server_e' at line 3

Comment: It seems like your db version is under 12. Try other solution.

Comment: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'server_events.time_stamp/3600 TM FROM     `msp-data`.server_events INNER JOIN   ' at line 3

Comment: you have two group by and order by with a ) which is not closing anything

Comment: this is the response

Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: The goal here, is to know in every day range like

00 - 1am / 1am - 2am 

To put in a graphic and know how many event_types = "auth_final" we have

Comment: try deleting second group by. i am trying to coding it blind

Comment: The response of your last update:
Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: try adding any alias after last closing

Answer (score 0):

@ismetguzelgun

```
SELECT SUM(CNT), TM FROM(SELECT 
    count(A.event_type) cnt,
    hotspots.partner_id,
    hotspots.partner,
    hotspots.operator_id,
    TM
FROM
    (SELECT 
        A.time_stamp/3600 AS TM,
        A.* FROM `msp-data`.server_events A
    ) A
INNER JOIN 
    `adserver`.hotspots, 
    `adserver`.operator
WHERE 
    A.time_stamp between "1591930800" and "1592017199" -- variable
    and A.event_type = "auth_final"
    and A.nas_id = adserver.hotspots.code
--     and hotspots.partner_id = "1" -- variable
--     and hotspots.operator_id = "2" -- variable
    GROUP BY
        hotspots.partner_id,
        hotspots.partner,
        hotspots.operator_id,
        TM
) B    
GROUP BY TM
ORDER BY
    2
```

Gave this output now:

```
SUM(CNT) TM
6   442206.9253
6   442207.1419
6   442207.9306
6   442208.9175
6   442209.0614
6   442209.2531
6   442209.3533
6   442209.4050
6   442209.4150
6   442209.4969
6   442210.0175
6   442210.1089
6   442210.4747
6   442211.6994
6   442211.7619
6   442212.9272
6   442213.4872
6   442214.0711
6   442214.7964
6   442215.4461
6   442215.5736
6   442215.8106
6   442216.2833
6   442216.2908
6   442216.7419
6   442217.5386
6   442217.6267
6   442218.0083
6   442218.3764
6   442219.4092
6   442219.6553
6   442219.8953
6   442219.9933
6   442220.3000
6   442220.9611
6   442221.0033
6   442221.0297
6   442221.6656
6   442221.7533
6   442221.7897
```

Comment: You should add a case statement on your TM. Like CASE WHEN TM> 1591930800 AND TM< 1592017199  THEN 'X -Y' WHEN ... THEN ... END. It will print your result in your intended way.

Comment: I write this code without all of your data. You should change it the way you want. It is just give you the idea.